# C# WTelegramClient Telegram-API How to programmatically click a button in a message from Telegram-Bot

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

The program communicates with Telegram-Bot. A text message is sent to the bot. The bot responds to the message. The answer contains 3 buttons. Question: How to click on a button programmatically?

Create a Telegram client:

```
_client = new WTelegram.Client(Config):
_user = await _client.LoginUserIfNeeded();
```

Finding a bot:

```
var contacts = await _client.Contacts_Search("@Search_bot", 20);
contacts.users.TryGetValue(1911124859, out peerBot));
```

Sending a request (message) to the Bot:

```
var message = await _client.SendMessageAsync(peerBot, "REQUEST");
```

We get an answer:

```
var differenceMessages = await _client.Updates_GetDifference(state.pts, state.date, state.qts);
```

We understand the answer. We find a button.
How to send a message to the Bot that we clicked on the button?

```
TL.Message tLMessage = null;
if (differenceMessages != null)
{
    if(differenceMessages.NewMessages != null)
    {
        foreach (var difference in differenceMessages.NewMessages)
        {
            tLMessage = difference as TL.Message;
            if(tLMessage != null && tLMessage.peer_id.ID == peerBot.ID )
            {
                if (!(tLMessage.reply_markup is ReplyMarkup replyMarkup)) continue;
                TL.ReplyInlineMarkup replyInlineMarkup = (ReplyInlineMarkup)replyMarkup;
                if (replyInlineMarkup.rows[2].buttons[0].Text == "Check text on Button")
                {
                    ***//TODO We want to click on this button!***
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An inline button can be [one of several types](https://core.telegram.org/type/KeyboardButton).
Let's assume you're talking about a [Callback button](https://core.telegram.org/constructor/keyboardButtonCallback) (that sends its callback to the bot)..

Searching through the [full list of API methods available](https://core.telegram.org/methods), you would quickly find that the right method to proceed to clicking on that button is [messages.getBotCallbackAnswer](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getBotCallbackAnswer) (so `Messages_GetBotCallbackAnswer` in WTelegramClient naming)

Therefore, in your case, you would write something like this:

```cs
    if (msg is TL.Message tlMessage && tlMessage.reply_markup is ReplyInlineMarkup replyInlineMarkup)
    {
        if (replyInlineMarkup.rows[ROW].buttons[COLUMN] is KeyboardButtonCallback btnCallback)
        {
            var answer = await client.Messages_GetBotCallbackAnswer(peerBot, tlMessage.id, data: btnCallback.data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dear Library Creator. I am very grateful for the time spent. Your code works great! Thank you!